# Exporting data from firebase database in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I want to have in my variable "data" the specific values/information from my database in firebase but I have this error - "*firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default.database is not a function"

Here is my App.js:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase-config";


function App() {

  function databaseData() {
    const database = firebase.database().ref("schools");

    database.on("value", async snapshot => {
      const data = [];

      snapshot.forEach(childSnapShot => {
        const schoolTitles = {
          ID: childSnapShot.key.toString(),
          Titles: childSnapShot.val().title,
        };

        data.push(schoolTitles);
      });
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {data: [...prevState.data, ...data]};
      });
      console.log("data");
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      databaseData();
  }, []);

return (...);}
```

And here is my firebase-config:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);

export default { firebase, database };
```

Is there a way to fix that? Thank you in advance!

I want to be able to have the desired information in "data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the compat import for the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#add_the_js_sdk_and_initialize) and not for Firestore:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/compat/database";
```

and you should export with

```
export { firebase, database };
```

---

The [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) are two different database services offered by Firebase.

Comment: Sadly, still I get the same error as before